# Table aliases in H2 SQL Delete

Tags: sql, h2

I'm attempting to implement closure table for a hierarchical group based on [this](http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html)

With H2, the following doesn't seem possible:

```
delete link
  from closure p, closure link, closure c
 where p.parent = link.parent and c.child = link.child
   and p.child=PARENT_ITEM    and c.parent=CHILD_ITEM
```

Can this be rewritten to work on H2 since it doesn't look like H2 supports table aliases in the DELETE statement based on the [H2 grammar](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#delete)

Comment: Are you aware that H2 supports recursive queries? You could use a (simpler) adjacency model instead.

Comment: I was not aware - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a complete example is:

```
create table closure(parent int, child int);
insert into closure values(1, 10), (10, 100);

delete from closure where exists(
  select * from closure p, closure c
  where p.parent = closure.parent
  and c.child = closure.child
  and p.child=10
  and c.parent=1);
```